# Kotlin: would a coroutine job be cleaned up automatically when complete?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

Basically what the title says. The only additional question is that if the job is not cleaned up, would those jobs be additional overhead if we keep reusing the same parent scope to create new coroutines? Thanks

additional info:
I tried something like the following

```kotlin
suspend fun main() = supervisorScope {
    launch {
        println("inner ${this@supervisorScope.coroutineContext.job.children.count()}") //inner 1
    }
    delay(1000)
    println("outer ${this@supervisorScope.coroutineContext.job.children.count()}") //outer 0
}
```

So at least from here it looks like the parent scope don't need to keep track of the finished children.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "cleaned up"? Could you provide an example of a code where the clean up would be needed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you want to stop a coroutine from running you can do so like this:

```
job = launch {
    // your code
}

button.setOnClickListener() {
    job?.cancel()
}
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative

This is basically needed if you have a loop that you want to run for a while and then stop externally.